# The sup of an integral tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Consider a complete, finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$. Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset L^1(\mu)$ be a sequence such that $\sup_n\int|f_n|\,d\mu< \infty$. Furthermore, assume that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{E}|f_n|\,d\mu< \varepsilon$ whenever $\mu(E)< \delta$. I want to show the followings:
$$
(a)\text{ } \sup_n \int_{\{|f_n|\geq M\}} |f_n|\,d\mu \to 0\text{ as }M \to \infty.
$$
$$
(b)\text{ }\sup_n \int_{\{|f_n|\leq \delta\}} |f_n|\,d\mu \to 0\text{ as }\delta \to 0.
$$
I have the following proof for (a):

Let $E=\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|\geq M\}$. By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\mu(E)\leq \frac {1}{M} \int_{X} |f_{n}|\, d\mu\text{ }\forall n\in \mathbb {N}.
$$
Since $\mu(E)\to 0$ as $M\to \infty$, $\forall \delta>0$, $\mu(E)<\delta$ and therefore,
$$
\int_{E}|f_{n}|\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
Since this is true for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\in \mathbb {N}$,
$$
\int_{E}|f_{n}|\, d\mu=\int_{\{|f_n|\geq M\}} |f_n|\,d\mu \to 0\text{ as }M \to \infty.
$$
Taking the supremum on the left-hand side, we get
$$
\sup_{n}\int_{\{|f_n|\geq M\}} |f_n|\,d\mu \to 0\text{ as }M \to \infty.
$$
I wonder if my proof is coorect, and for (b), I wonder how to show that the measure of the set $\{|f_n|\leq \delta\}$ is small so that a similar argument can be stated as in (a)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to a) looks good. b) is in fact simpler. Recall that the space has finite measure, so

$$
\int_{\{|f_n|\leq \delta\}}|f_n|d\mu\leq \delta\int_{\{|f_n|\leq \delta\}}d \mu\leq \delta\mu(X)
$$
so
$$
\sup_{n}\int_{\{|f_n|\leq \delta\}}|f_n|d\mu\leq \delta\mu(X)\to 0
$$
as $\delta\to 0$.